# D3 Group Translate Overflow Issue

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I am not able to pinpoint the exact cause for this issue.
I am creating a dynamic legend for a chart and I wanted to place it at the exact center of a "container div". After the entire legend is created, I translate the group to a position that makes it at the center of the div.

However, what I see is that the SVG get "clipped" at 300px. In the sense, it sort of overflows some boundary and that portion of the SVG graphic is not visible.

I have put up the example code at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/7Ja4Y/) here.

I apologize in advance for the jumble of code that is written in the above link.

This is what I use for translating the svg.

```
d3.select(".avs-legend-group").attr("transform", "translate("+ xOffset + ",0)");
```

-where ".avs-legend-group" is a class that holds the "g" group element.

Comment: What like in [this Firefox browsershot](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/9e92f997c91e00e6e2fd2a5e27cd1905)? Worked for me in [chrome](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/fd032191ea696a407117936f6093a07f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a browser issue (Firefox) where the width of the SVG has not been specified explicitly.

What the SVG spec says should happen in this case is

> **width = "<length>"**
>
> For outermost svg elements, the intrinsic width of the SVG document fragment. For embedded ‘svg’ elements, the width of the rectangular region into which the ‘svg’ element is placed.
>
> A negative value is an error (see Error processing). A value of zero disables rendering of the element.
>
> **If the attribute is not specified, the effect is as if a value of '100%' were specified.**
>
> Animatable: yes.

[SVG 1.1 (Second Edition) – 16 August 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElementWidthAttribute) (emphasis mine)

Seems if you supply the implicit value of 100% explicitly to the containing SVG this issue in Firefox is resolved.

```
var svg = d3.select("#" + uniqueIdentifier)
    .append("svg")
            .attr('width', '100%');
```

You can check this for yourself with an ammended [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZfEs/)

Comment: I never checked in Chrome. My bad. 
I am new to SVG and hadn't read this specific piece on widths. This is a great answer. Thanks for the guidance on the spec!